# Amazon EKS from local kubectl does not cache MFA token/session

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cli

I have set up an EKS cluster in AWS. My user-account there is secured with MFA. And I have an `assumerole`, that is allowed to manage my infrastructure.

So I installed and configured my system as stated in the AWS userguide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html

I have `kubectl` in version 1.11.x installed, so I can use that binary to communicate with aws (and I do not need the patched amazon version). I then installed `aws-cli` and `aws-iam-authenticator`.

```
user@notebook [04:44:51 PM] [~]
-> % kubectl version --short --client
Client Version: v1.11.0
user@notebook [04:45:13 PM] [~]
-> % aws-iam-authenticator help
A tool to authenticate to Kubernetes using AWS IAM credentials
...
user@notebook [04:45:25 PM] [~]
-> % aws --version
aws-cli/1.15.51 Python/3.6.6 Linux/4.17.8-1-ARCH botocore/1.10.50
user@notebook [04:45:30 PM] [~]
-> %
```

I then created the configuration files from the how-to `~/.aws/credentials`, `~/.aws/config`, `~/.kube_aws/config` and created an alias for myself to use `kubectl` with the new config (since I have more clusters to manage): `alias kubectlaws='KUBECONFIG=/home/user/.kube_aws/config kubectl $@'`.

So here comes my problem: When I connect to the cluster using the `aws-cli` binary, I have to enter my MFA token and then the *session* is cached (I read for about 15 minutes).

```
user@notebook [04:58:52 PM] [~]
-> % aws eks describe-cluster --profile my_profile --name ClusterName  --query cluster.status                                                                                          
Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::<MY_MFA_ARN>:
"ACTIVE"
user@notebook [04:59:09 PM] [~]
-> % aws eks describe-cluster --profile my_profile --name ClusterName  --query cluster.endpoint                                                                                        
"https://..."
user@notebook [04:59:30 PM] [~]
-> %
```

But when I do this with my `kubectl` alias, I have to enter the token every time I run a command! Furthermore, I cannot re-use a code, so I have to wait about 30 seconds, until the next one is provided.

```
user@notebook [05:03:56 PM] [~]
-> % kubectlaws get nodes
Assume Role MFA token code: 123456
NAME                             STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
...
user@notebook [05:04:05 PM] [~]
-> % kubectlaws get nodes
Assume Role MFA token code: 123456
could not get token: AccessDenied: MultiFactorAuthentication failed with invalid MFA one time pass code.                                                                                      
        status code: 403, request id: <SOME_ID>
No resources found.
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: exit status 1
user@notebook [05:04:14 PM] [~]
-> %
```

This is really annoying, as you might imagine. Has anyone any idea what I did wrong there? Is this a bug? Or is this some kind of mis-configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is a pain. I've been fighting with it for the whole day yesterday, but managed to get it working, let's see if our cases are similar enough.

My guess is that the *usual* `aws configure` configuration with a MFA ARN + the AWS SDK used to develop *kubectl* are not entirely compatible: I have two profiles set for this, one that has its *mfa_serial_arn* and *role_arn* that works as follows:

- First **aws** command I type, I get prompted for MFA token
- From there onwards, while session is active, I can work without typing in more tokens.
- *kubectl* asks for a token EVERY SINGLE TIME.

This is bad.

Now, I set a different profile, without any of the above, and I do the following:

```

```
keys=($(aws sts assume-role --role-arn <ARN_OF_DELEGATED_ROLE> \
   --role-session-name  <RANDOM_UNIQUE_NAME> \
   --serial-number <ARN_OF_MFA_DEVICE>\
   --token-code  \
    --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]' --output text))

# profile used here will be configured in ~/.aws/credentials
export AWS_PROFILE=<PROFILE YOU WANT>

aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${temp_keys[0]}
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${temp_keys[1]}
aws configure set aws_session_token ${temp_keys[2]}
```

```

This creates a **temporary valid** aws profile, that can be used **BOTH** with the aws cli, and kubectl.

Comment: Ok, let me try that. I'm not sure if I completely get it, but I'll check and come back to you, if I have questions :) Thanks!

Comment: Hm. Could not get this to work... I execute the above command with a `RANDOM_UNIQUE_NAME` I just made up and a `TOKEN_VALUE` from my MFA device (I just left the `MFA_TOKEN_VALUE` part out. it was just the var used afterwards, right?) and got a block with credentials (`AccessKeyId`, `SecretAccessKey`, `SessionToken`, `Expiration`) and an `AssumedRoleUser` back. `aws configure` lets me just set the access key id and secret. So what do I do with the other info? And what do I do with the session name?

Comment: So, the end result should be a _valid_ block of credentials in the `~/.aws/credentials` file, for the profile you want to use with _kubectl_, let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Btw: I managed to fix this problem by using `aws-mfa` (https://github.com/broamski/aws-mfa), which I have configured to cache my aws credentials for an hour.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone came here to solve this problem without any workarounds - the solution is simple.

We need to add switch `--cache` to the kubeconfig for a user used to access a Kubernetes cluster.

```
users:
- name: <redacted>
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - --cache
      - -i
      - prod
```

Tested on:

```
$ aws-iam-authenticator version
{"Version":"v0.5.1","Commit":"d7c0b2e9131faabb2b09dd804a35ee03822f8447"}
```

Hope this will help someone.